# Gestures with Delphi (prior to D2010)

Tags: delphi, gestures

Has anyone heard of third party mouse gesture support for versions of Delphi prior to Delphi 2010? All I want is to be able to respond to a right mouse hold down for "swipe left" and "swipe right".

Comment: I found an [article](http://www.tecepe.com.br/d7gestures/) about implementing mouse gestures with Delphi 7 but it relies on the gesture support in Windows 7 and 8 and it isn't a complete solution so it might not be what your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A swipe left or swipe right is nothing else than a comparison between your X-Coordinates.
Just compare your X-Coordinate in your `OnMouseDown` Event with the X-Coordinate in your `OnMouseUp` Event.
If the result is positive, it's a Swipe-Left. If the result is negative, it's a Swipe-Right.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I wanted to upscale this function so that visible mouse trails appear (temporarily), like you see with many mouse gesture extensions for Firefox and Chrome? Do-able?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.tecepe.com.br/d7gestures/ Maybe the last code example can give you a clue how to use Canvas. Try it to use with the OnMouseMove Event. There you also have your X and Y Coordinates.